# Current Stack frame was not found in a loaded module

Tags: python, scope

Im relatively new to python, and the scoping rules dont make much sense to me. I have not been able to find really any help to this problem. When i call `Start(ToolTester.RUString)` in places where its not within a class, it will run but when I try it here I get

```
Frame not in module. the Current stack frame was not found in a loaded module. Source cannot be shown for this location.
```

here is the code for the file. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
import DataFunctions
import automa
from DataFunctions import *
from automa.api import *

class ToolTester():

    def ClickOnCalculator(self, readableTimeStamp):
        try:
            RetailWindow = start(r"C:\Users\mhunt\Source\Workspaces\Retail Utilities\Retail Utilities\Retail Utilities\bin\Debug\Retail Utilities.exe")
            click("POS")
            click(TextField("Associate Code"))
            write("722345")
            click("Enter")
            click(TextField("Shift Owner: System Admin"))
            write("722345")
            click("Enter")
            click("Tools")
            click("Calculator")
            click("Close")
            click("System", "Close/Suspend Shift")
            click("yes")
            kill(RetailWindow)

            file = open("%s.txt" %readableTimeStamp, "a")
            file.write("ToolsCalculator Passed!\n")
            file.close()
            IncrementingTestPassedCounter.incrementTestPassed(readableTimeStamp)
        except:
            file = open("%s.txt" %readableTimeStamp, "a")
            file.write("ToolsCalculator Failed!\n")
            file.close()
            IncrementingTestFailedCounter.incrementTestFailed(readableTimeStamp)
```

here is the main file

```
import Tests
from Tests import *
import DataFunctions
from DataFunctions import *
import datetime
import time
from decimal import Decimal
from ToolsTesting import *

#txt file written to keep track of results. File name is the timestamp from     when the file was started
timeStamp = time.time()
readableTimeStamp =     datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timeStamp).strftime("%Y.%m.%d %H.%M.%S")
Tests.ResultsFileSetup.Setup(readableTimeStamp)
toolTester = ToolsTesting.ToolTester()
toolTester.ClickOnCalculator(readableTimeStamp)
toolTester.ClickOnPrintAMDMatrix(readableTimeStamp)
toolTester.ClickOnReturnAllocation(readableTimeStamp)
```

Comment: You have BUGS! Code indentation is wrong in your example code, there fore this scope is violated as well. And you are setting ToolTester.RUString instead of self.RUString. Are you sure you want to do that?

Comment: edited the spacing, still has same issues

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I think this is exactly your problem:

```
# You do not call or set an attribute of a class from within a method of that classes instance
# So:
class ToolTester:
    RUString = ""
    def __init__ (self):
        self.RUString = "I am string"

    def GetTheString (self):
        return self.RUString
```

Changing ToolTester.RUString instead of self.RUString changes the attribute of a class, not of the object instantiated from it.
To do this is unusual and it's done only in special occasions.
That is a scope problem Python refered to, I hope.

Comment: just to make sure that there is no issue i removed that part of the code. I still have the same error as before

Comment: In main file, you did "from ToolTesting import *" which means that the ToolTester() is loaded in main scope, (compare to C #include). Either change that to "import ToolTesting" or remove its reference, then it is "Tester = ToolTester()".

Comment: But for why this would raise stack frame error, I do not know. The error you should get for that should be "NameError: global variable 'ToolTesting' is not defined" So maybe is something more than that.